# Excel count unique in range if

Tags: excel, formula

What formula can be used to count unique values in column A if Column B is a value. i have seen many online but none of them seem to work when only using Column ranges , the data will be of varied length so only column ref can be used

this worked

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A18<>"")*(B1:B18=$D$1)/COUNTIF(A1:A18,A1:A18))
```

but not when changed to

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")*(B:B=$D$1)/COUNTIF(A:A,A:A))
```

table

```
  A           B         C         D          E
12/12/2015  criteria1           criteria1      3
12/12/2015  criteria1           
13/12/2015  criteria1           
13/12/2015  criteria1           
14/12/2015  criteria1           
14/12/2015  criteria1           
18/12/2015  criteria2           
19/12/2015  criteria2           
20/12/2015  criteria2           
21/12/2015  criteria2           
22/12/2015  criteria2           
23/12/2015  criteria2           
24/12/2015  criteria3           
25/12/2015  criteria3           
26/12/2015  criteria3           
27/12/2015  criteria3           
28/12/2015  criteria3           
29/12/2015  criteria3
```

I Have also tried sumproduct with frequency but always got N/A

Comment: Sumproduct can't use whole column references.  You'll have to find a different approach.

Comment: "A further improvement is that in Excel 2007, SUMPRODUCT can address a whole column" , is this not true?

Comment: doh!  What rock have I been living under?!

Comment: I get a #DIV/0 error.  I wonder if it's a memory issue.  SUMPRODUCT is evaluating all 1,000,000+ rows of data, so while you *may* be able to use whole column references with Sumproduct, I don't think it's the right approach.

Comment: The fact that the dataset is of varied length does not at all mean that entire columns should be used as a reference. Do you really have data that potentially extends up to row one million-plus? Can you not set a lower upper bound than that? Even better, of course, is to define your range as a dynamic one, which automatically expands/contracts as the data changes. Do you know how to do this? Finally, this SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIF combination is astonishingly slow. FREQUENCY and MATCH is far quicker for this.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are in `A1:B18`, and `criteria1` is in `C1`, try:

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A18<>"", IF(B1:B18=C1, MATCH(A1:A18, A1:A18, 0))), ROW(A1:A18)-ROW(A1)+1), 1))}
```

Expanded:

```
{=SUM(
    IF(
        FREQUENCY(
            IF(A1:A18<>"", 
                IF(B1:B18=C1, 
                    MATCH(A1:A18, A1:A18, 0)
                )
            ), 
            ROW(A1:A18)-ROW(A1)+1
        ), 
    1)
)}
```

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Good construction. Hopefully now the OP can just realise the error in their ways re referencing entire columns!